# thirsty to quench = hungry to?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What would be an appropriate word to be used to define the feeling of having great food when you were really hungry?

or in other words

what will be the appropriate word for hungry if need to be used in the similar sense of quenching for being thirsty?

Comment: I don't think there are any specific (exactly correspond) words to fill the gap, but what are usually used are 'satisfied', 'eased', 'alleviated', 'lessen', 'reduce'. Look up synonyms of those.

Answer (score 2):

"Sated" might be the word you're looking for.   As Mitch said, I don't know that it's *exactly* analogous to quench, but it's pretty similar.   (Ex. "The burger sated my hunger.")   Idiomatically, you could say "That burger really hit the spot."